# How to add new Pod property in yaml in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I want to add new pod property in yaml file while creating pod in Kubernetes.
By looking at old properties I did all required changes in the kubernetes source code but I still get below parsing error:

*error: error validating "podbox.yml": error validating data: found invalid field newproperty for v1.Pod*

Example Pod yaml file :

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: podbox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: podbox
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "1"
  restartPolicy: Always
  newproperty: false
```

```
`newproperty`
```

not getting parsed while creating Pod.

Is there any specific changes required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to add new fields to `kind: Pod`, because then your Kubernetes code will be on a fork and your config will be non-portable.

If you are planning a contribution to submit to the code Kubernetes code, you should first join the appropriate SIG (sig-node or sig-apps for Pod changes) and get support for your proposed change.  Someone there can point you to example PRs that you can follow to add a field.

If you just need to put some extra information in a Pod that you or your own programs can parse, then use an [annotation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/).

If you want to create a new type in your Kubernetes cluster, use a [Custom Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/api-extension/custom-resources/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how do I add one more resource type like CPU and memory in resource MAP in yaml file.                                   Example:                                                                                     requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
 newResource: "16Mi"

Comment: Can we add new property at spec level in yaml file.(code in question updated)?

Comment: We are maintaining our own code repository for changes made by us

Comment: I'd follow Eric's recommendation and add it as annotation, that what they are for. If it's extended functionality use Customer Resources (CRDs formerly TPR). Your custom controller or scheduler can then act upon that. Forking the K8s repo to just add a field wouldn't be very beneficial as with each upstream update you'd have to rebase and build again.

Comment: If all you want to introduce is an opaque integer resource which does not require any special support across the system, then follow this - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#opaque-integer-resources-alpha-feature

Comment: If you want first class support for a resource across the system, this is WIP. https://github.com/kubernetes/community/pull/695/files is one step in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line

`newproperty: false`

from your YAML and you should be fine.

Comment: I want to add this as a new property in pod

Comment: Eric answered it quite well above (see my comment above)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you should be declaring then inside data:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: podbox
  namespace: default
data:
  newproperty: false
```

if you want an enviroment variable to be passed to the docker use this structure:

```
....
 containers:
  - name: name
    image: some_image
    env:
    - name: SOME_VAR
      value: "Hello from the kubernetes"
....
```

Comment: @puja I have update response with a more exact approach